# Promise join change to promise all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I've read that the promise join was deprecated 
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html

My question is

- how should I change this code to promise **all**, and if there is **better**
  way to write this code( the code is working!) but I want to get your feedback but the code should have the same logic as below
- there is a tool to node js with ***bluebird*** which can track if i've unfinished promise chain

```js
createProc = function (fPath) {
    "use strict";
    return Promise.join(
        fs.readFileAsync(fPath, 'utf8')
            .then(function (content) {
                return parseFile(content).getWeb();
            }),
        scan.findInUseAsync(12, 152, 'localhost')
            .then(envOptions.mod.bind(null, process.env))
    ).then(function (args) {
            return inter.Process('run', args[0], args[1]);
        }).then(function (result) {
            return result.stdout;
        }, function (error) {
            return error;
        });
};
```

Comment: That link doesn't say that `Promise.join()` has been deprecated, does it?

Comment: @SlashmanX - please see the node below the code in the link

Comment: I did, that doesn't say the `Promise.join()` is deprecated, just that a way it used to work is. `Promise.join()` is still ok to use

Comment: @SlashmanX - thanks but still I need to change it to promise all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to switch to `Promise.all()`, it just takes an array of promises as an argument and doesn't accept a callback (which you aren't using anyway).  So, all you have to do is to wrap the two promises you are passing in an array:

```
createProc = function (fPath) {
    "use strict";
    return Promise.all([
        // added here  ^
        fs.readFileAsync(fPath, 'utf8')
            .then(function (content) {
                return parseFile(content).getWeb();
            }),
        scan.findInUseAsync(12, 152, 'localhost')
            .then(envOptions.mod.bind(null, process.env))
    ]).then(function (args) {
            return inter.Process('run', args[0], args[1]);
        }).then(function (result) {
            return result.stdout;
        }, function (error) {
            return error;
        });
};
```

Comment: Thanks 1+, for the two other question does the code is writed ok,(I see in some places that they create empty array and put the promise there and then pass the array to the chain but not sure how to use it here...) or do you think it can be improved, 2 .how can I track unfinished promise chain

Comment: @Mark - An unfinished promise chain is tracked by attaching a `.then()` handler to it so you get called when it finishes.  I'm not sure what else you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

> there is a tool to node js with bluebird which can track if i've unfinished promise chain

There is a pull request that's still actively being discussed in [the issue tracker](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/pull/929) the proposed API would let you track those.

> and if there is better way to write this code

Well, you're writing a lot of redundant code. Also, `join` takes a function as its last argument. Node supports some pretty cool features:

```
 // module itself should be strict, use arrows they're fun
const createProc = fPath => Promise.join(
    fs.readFileAsync(fPath, 'utf8').then(parseFile).call("getWeb")
    scan.findInUseAsync(12, 152, 'localhost').then(_ => envOptions.mod(process.env)),
    args => inter.Process('run', args[0], args[1]);
).get("stdout"); // don't do that silly `return error` thing, propagate exceptions
```

Comment: HI Benjamin thanks for replay! 1+ you write you are using a lot of redundant code since we are using node 0.12.7 we dont have arrow function how you should adopt the code witout the arrow to skip the redundant code ?

Comment: First - don't use really old versions of Node :) Second, if you do, you can run your code through Babel. Third - arrows in this case just translate to (function(arg){